# Interactive Field Extraction (Regex)

Tags: regex, splunk

I have my xml data [HERE](http://pastebin.com/98zg3tRX), I need to extract using Splunk IFX, Generated pattern (regex).

Example Xml: `<d:Message>(22/7)17:53 Accident on AYE (towards Tuas) after Jurong Port Rd Exit. Avoid lane 3.</d:Message>`

I have this expression that extract from word after until Exit. 
`(?i) after (?P<wordafter>.[^\.]*?Exit)`

As this look for word Exit only, how do I add other situation such as Rd|Entrance ? 
I tried `(?i) after (?P<wordafter>.[^\.]*?Exit|Entrance|Rd)`, it wont work.

Comment: Almost every programming language has xml parser and that would be definitely better tool than Regex.

Comment: I need to use Splunk IFX that is regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to surround alternation with `()` like `(?i) after (?P<wordafter>.[^\.]*?(Exit|Entrance|Rd))`.

Well, if it doesn't like unnamed groups, maybe you can do it this?

```
(?i) after (?P<wordafter>.[^\.]*?(?P<dummy>Exit|Entrance|Rd))
```

Comment: I tired that and had this error Invalid regex: no named extraction at position 39 (i.e., "?(Exit|Ent..."). Expected "(?P<variable>pattern)"